# Unexplained Google Maps Geocoding OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: perl, google-maps

I have a Perl script that uses Google's geocoding at a slow rate but today I'm hitting the 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT' error.

I'm fully signed up with billing and well below any budget limits.

In the last 30 days Google says I've made 2,074 Geocoding API requests (with 0.1% errors) and they would be evenly distributed over the 30 days.

I've bumped the quotas up to unlimited, per 100 up to 5,000 (max) and per 100 per user to unlimited and still the error occurs.

The relevant Perl would be:

```
use Google::GeoCoder::Smart;

my ($resultnum, $error, @results, $returncontent) = $geo->geocode("address" => $g, "key" => "valid_key_hidden", "region" => "au");
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you looked at the debugging process outlined in https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits ? The 24h limits are checked/reset once a day, so maybe you have to wait 24 hours. Also, maybe change your token just in case it has been leaked.

Comment: Issue was the perl module being used was too old and was hardcoded to use http not https. It also had a parameter for setting the api key, but never sent it.  I've discarded the module in favour of a direct call to the api url.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the perl module being used was too old and was hardcoded to use http not https. It also had a parameter for setting the api key, but never sent it.

I've discarded the module in favour of a direct call to the api url